# Why does magento 2 use hard coded "Factory" class?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.1, class, factory

As I've checked in Magento 2.3.1 Sales module there is one hardcoded **Factory** file in below path:

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/CollectionFactory.php

And in Cms module there is no **Factory** file available

> vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/ResourceModel/Block/Collection.php

I've read concept regarding factories which are automatically generated but I was surprised when I saw hardcoded **Factory** file. So just wanted to know the reason behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not dam sure why Magento use hardcoded Factory class but I think they need to use hardcoded factory class because of while installing default Magento they need to set default data like order, system config data, reports or any other data to display default value in fresh Magento.

I have checked and see that `vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/CollectionFactory` class impliment `CollectionFactoryInterface` and that **interface** Create class instance with specified parameters. see the below diagram.

[image: diagram]

Below are some the hardcoded factory class.

- > Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\CollectionFactory
- > magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/CollectionFactory

[See refrance link](https://www.magentoextensions.org/documentation/class_magento_1_1_reports_1_1_model_1_1_resource_model_1_1_quote_1_1_collection_factory.html).

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I reckon if you delete and let magento generate factory class you will be missing some functionality. Therefore this was done for no reason other that it served the purpose of edits made to the file.

Even with the best intentions sometimes rules need to be broken.